# opening a model in html after getting response from api in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in html where i click on submit to hit an api .After hitting the api , i get some response and on basis of that i need to open a model .
How do we achieve this ?

```
    <div class="container mr-0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 contact-form pb-5">
              <div class="sign-up">
                <h4>Get Quote</h4>
              </div>
              <form onsubmit="myFunction('myForm')" id="myForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name of company" type="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Number of employees" type="number" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contact person name" type="name" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contact person email" type="email" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contact person mobile number" type="number" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="pt-3">  
                <!-- <button type="submit"  class="get-button-light">SUBMIT</button> -->
                <button type="submit" class="get-button-light" " >SUBMIT</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="col-md-2"></div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 position-relative">

          <div class="lets-start">
            <img src="./assets/images4/lets-start.png"  width="100%">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Code for model in same html .

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content inner-content">

<!-------------->
<section class="all-done">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 p-4" >
<div class="all-bg">
<h4>Done</h4>
<p>Team <span>Vital</span> will connect with you in <br>next 24 hours .</p>
<div class=" text-right">
<img src="assets/images4/base-plan-like.png" />
</div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-------------->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My fellow developer did this on submit button
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
 but it opens up model even when api has not been hit .How can we control this from javascript .on click of submit  ,i have hit an api .my concern is how to do it with javascript .

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger model after your API response using the call

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
```

Here the call back function triggers after modal is opened.

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

[***DOCUMENTATION***](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals)